# How do I get the request URL for message headers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I have an inbound gateway to process JSON payloads.  Since we utilize the same backend service as our SOAP endpoints, I need to have an inbound gateway that maps to all paths.  I can see the default HTTP headers come across the into the message, but I specifically need the request URL so I can parse it and route to the appropriate serve as needed.

My inbound-gateway:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="JSONGateway"
        path="*" request-channel="JSONRequestChannel" supported-methods="POST"
        reply-timeout="5000" 
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        request-payload-type="java.lang.String" >
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

I tried adding a header-enricher like I do for SOAP, but the TransportContextListener is null.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channelJSONequestChannel"
    output-channel="JSONRequestChannelWithHeaders">

    <int:header name="service"
        expression="T(org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContextHolder).transportContext.connection.uri.toString().substring(T(org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContextHolder).transportContext.connection.uri.toString().lastIndexOf('/')+1)" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

I need a way to get the URL of the request so I can parse out the service into the message headers for my downstream router.

```
/json/ContactService = "ContactService"
/json/ContactService/insert = "ContactService"
/json/ContactService/get/234 = "ContactService"
```

I also tried adding a header-mapper class, but still run into the same problem.  How can I get a handle to the HTTPServletRequest in code?  Once I get that I can get all the headers I need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't check the message headers.

After converting `ServletServerHttpRequest` to the `Message` it gets these headers by default:

```
Message<?> message = messageBuilder
                    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL,
                            request.getURI().toString())
                    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_METHOD,
                            request.getMethod().toString())
                    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL,
                            servletRequest.getUserPrincipal())
                    .build();
```

So, `http_requestUrl` is for you to go ahead and parse it appropriately.